# How to fix View returning a blank page? (HTTP Status Code 405 - Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, http-status-code-405

I have an Index page that allows users to see a list of Stocks. Users can add stocks to their watchlist by clicking an Add to Watchlist button. This leads to the Watchlist page, sending the User's ID and the stock they want to add to their watchlist so their watchlist can be persisted any time they log into their account.

I need the method to be HTTPPost because I don't want the user's ID as part of the query string, as this is sensitive info. The Watchlist action method serves the purpose of inserting the stock information and the user's ID as a record in a Watchlist table and also display the user's watchlist for them to see.

This is where the problem comes in. I keep getting an HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error. I've checked my syntax in code and everything seems fine. I have a feeling it might have to do with passing two values (stock Ticker and user ID) instead of one.

I'll display relevant code in the order of operation.

Index.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@model StockView.Models.StockExchangeViewModel
@inject UserManager<GenericUser> UserManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var userID = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
    string UserId = (string)userID;
}

<h1>Stocks</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-controller="Stocks" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>

        <select asp-for="StockExchange" asp-items="Model.Exchanges">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stocks[0].Ticker)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stocks[0].Price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stocks[0].Volume)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stocks[0].MarketCap)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stocks[0].Exchange)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Stocks)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ticker)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Volume)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarketCap)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Exchange)
                </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Ticker">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Ticker">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Ticker">Delete</a> |
                <a href="@Url.Action("Watchlist", "Stocks", new { stockTicker = item.Ticker, userId = UserId})">Add To Watchlist</a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Chart", "Stocks", new {stockTicker = item.Ticker})">View Chart</a>
                
            </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

StocksController.cs

```
 //This method is meant to post into a Watchlist object which is persisted by the database
        
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Watchlist(string stockTicker, string userId)
        {
            try
            {

                var stock = from s in _context.Stocks
                            where s.Ticker == stockTicker
                            select new { s.Ticker, s.Price, s.Exchange };
                Stocks tempStock = (Stocks)stock;

             
                //Insert into watchlist using stock attributes: UserId, Ticker, Price, Exchange


                await _context.Watchlists.AddAsync(new Watchlist
                {
                    GenericUserId = userId,
                    Ticker = tempStock.Ticker,
                    Price = tempStock.Price,
                    Exchange = tempStock.Exchange
                });
                _context.SaveChanges();

                var stocks = from s in _context.Watchlists
                             where s.GenericUserId == userId
                             select new { s.Ticker, s.Price, s.Exchange };


                ViewBag.stocks = stocks;
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error",
            new ErrorViewModel
            {
                RequestId = ex.ToString(),
                Description = "Error." + ex.Message
            });
            }
        }
```

I've tried changing the HTTP Attributes but I doubt that is the root of the problem, I've also tried to see if the action method performs any of the logic, and unfortunately, nothing is being persisted into the database at this time.

Everything seems to make sense, I'm not sure what I could be missing.

I can also provide any extra code that might paint a clearer picture.

Comment: *"I don't want the user's ID as part of the query string, as this is sensitive info"* - Making it a POST isn't much better, if any. Sure, it won't be on the URL, but it's still open and visible to an attacker. There's a difference between "needs to be kept out of over-the-shoulder view" and "sensitive" (your word).

Comment: Like  
madreflection said: "Making it a POST isn't much better".  PROBLEM: Your form is doing a "GET" (vs. your intention, a "POST")

Comment: I see. Well, let's discard that for now. The form in the Index.cshtml file isn't passing the User ID and stockTicker. That form is filtering stocks on the page by ticker or stockExchange. I'm passing the data using the anchor tag at the bottom  <a href="@Url.Action("Watchlist", "Stocks", new { stockTicker = item.Ticker, userId = UserId})">Add To Watchlist</a>; Is it possible that the error might be in the way I'm passing the data to my controller?

Comment: An anchor tag can only directly produce a `GET` request. WebForms circumvented this restriction by invoking a JavaScript function (named "__doPostBack") that submitted the `form` which always had `method="post"`. If you have to use an anchor tag, you'll have to use the same technique if you want to do a `POST`.

Comment: On a side note, the User's ID should never need to, or be allowed to come from the client, either by GET or POST. That should be pulled and verified as part of the session state credentials server-side. Any time an operation comes from the client to request or modify data, the server should check that the Auth is present and valid, and that the current User ID from that Auth has permission for the requested record. The moment a requested ID isn't associated to the current Auth user ID, Situation Logged and Session ended.

Comment: @madreflection Thank you for the clarification, that piece of knowledge is good to know.

Comment: @StevePy Thanks for this advice. I'm still learning the importance of security, and for this small project, I want things to work before I optimize the code and improve security features. Regardless, I appreciate the knowledge. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anchor Tag can only send `HttpGet` request and your `Watchlist` action can only receive HttpPost request, This is the reason why you get `HTTP Status Code 405 - Method Not Allowed`.

You can just remove `[HttpPost]` attribute to let `Watchlist` action receive Http Get request. Because your Anchor Tag will generate url like `xxx/Stocks/Watchlist?stockTicker=xxxx&userId=xxxx`, If `Watchlist` is Http Get method, It's parameter will bind value from query string. But this method may not fit your requirement because it will show userId in query string.

Another method is send Http Post request to access `Watchlist` action. Because Anchor Tag can't send Post request, You can add some css style to make button look like a Anchor Tag.

```
.inline {
    display: inline;
}

.link-button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: serif;
}

    .link-button:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    .link-button:active {
        color: red;
    }
```

[image]

Then change your `Add To Watchlist` Anchor Tag to:

```
<button type="button" id="Edit" value="item.Ticker" data-value="userId" class="link-button" onclick="Watchlist(this)">
        Add To Watchlist
</button>
```

Then write a JavaScript code to send post in ajax.

```
<script>
    function Watchlist(button) {
        var result1 = button.value;
        var result2 = button.getAttribute("data-value");
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("stockTicker",result1);
        formdata.append("userId", result2);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Stocks/Watchlist',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of `method` attribute of your form element as `post`:

```
<form asp-controller="Stocks" asp-action="Index" method="post">
```

Comment: This form is different, I'm sending data using the Anchor Tag  <a href="@Url.Action("Watchlist", "Stocks", new { stockTicker = item.Ticker, userId = UserId})">Add To Watchlist</a>

Comment: If you're using anchor tag, it will always send a get request. So, you have to change your attribute as HttpGet. This is about web request. Anchor tags with href attribute basically means 'send a get request to the server and show response as a webpage'.